# Next.JS with framer-motion does not change content on navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I have the following Link on my index page that links to my `About Us` page:

```
<Link href="/about"><a>About us</a></Link>
```

in my `_app.js` file, I have this `AnimatePresence` wrapper:

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
    <Component {...pageProps} key={router.route} />
</AnimatePresence>
```

Now, when I click my `About Us` link, the browser URL bar shows the new route, but the page content is still the index content.

But, when I remove the `AnimatePresence` wrapper, it works fine (no animation of course).

Why doesn't my animation work?

Answer (score 4):

Ah issue is I need to wrap my components with a motion wrapper like:

```
<motion.div
                initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
            >
```